# Netbeans - GlassFish - Java EE Configuration File

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, configuration-files

Since it was really difficult for me to find an answer to this question I'm gonna post both the question and the answer I found to this problem.

Problem: How to use a configuration file in java while working with Netbeans and deploying into a GlassFish Server?

Main problem is to actually access the file (a lot of trouble with the path in which things as getResource, creating a new File and getting it's absolute path, and many other tricks didn't work).

In this particular case I wanted the file to be in my ejb Project.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a configuration File (e.g. "config.properties") in
  ProjectName-ejb\src\conf

[image]

You will be able to see the file from Netbeans in your project configuration Files:

[image]

- Insert all the properties you want:

[image]

- Create an attribute in the class from which you will access the file like this: **private final String BAD_WORDS_FILE_NAME = "\META-INF\config.properties";**

Once your code is deployed to GlassFIsh, all conf files seem to be deployed to this META-INF folder:
[image]

- Access Properties using sth like:

`private String[] getBadWordsFromFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(BAD_WORDS_FILE_NAME);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(resourceAsStream);
        String badWordsAsString = properties.getProperty(BAD_WORDS_PROPERTY_NAME);
        return badWordsAsString.split(BAD_WORDS_SEPARATOR);
    }`

This was the Solution I found, which worked but was only tested on a local machine... this might get some trouble on Release.